# Swift - pruning elements from an Array, converting integer strings to integers

Tags: arrays, swift, types, swift2

I have an array that contains numbers and empty strings, like `["", "2", "4", "", "", "1", "2", ""]`. I would like to pare this down to a list of numbers, like `[2,4,1,2]`.

My first effort split this into two steps, first strip out the empty strings, then do the string-to-integer conversion. However, my code for step one isn't working as desired.

```
for (index,value) in tempArray.enumerate(){
    if value == ""  {
        tempArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

This fails, I believe because it is using the index values from the original, complete array, though after the first deletion they are not longer accurate.

What would be a better way to accomplish my goal, and what is the best way to convert the resulting array of integer strings to an array of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Swift 2 we can take advantage of `flatMap` and `Int()`:

```
let stringsArray = ["", "2", "4", "", "", "1", "2", ""]

let intsArray = stringsArray.flatMap { Int($0) }

print(intsArray)  // [2, 4, 1, 2]
```

Explanation: `Int()` returns `nil` if the string does not contain an integer, and `flatMap` ignores `nil`s and unwraps the optional `Int`s returned by `Int()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = ["", "2", "4", "", "", "1", "2", ""]

let filtered = str.filter {$0 != "" }

let intArr = filtered.map {($0 as NSString).integerValue}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer; I'm giving the checkmark to Eric D only because he posted first.