# How to store nil value after unwrapping optional?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I want to have array od data that stores either integers or nils. For instance:

`[1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7]`

How to do that using optionals?
When I play with it always end up with:

`[optional(1),optional(2)...]`

I can't force unwrap because it will crash anytime a value happens to be nil.

How to iterate over values and add to array both unwrapped values and nils if such occurs?

Comment: You could use `flatMap` http://stackoverflow.com/a/32876707/2227743

Comment: So... you want to `print` the array like this:`[1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7]`, instead of this: `[optional(1),optional(2)...]`. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do. Because I need to keep track which value is nil

Comment: "add to array both unwrapped values and nils" An array cannot contain both unwrapped values and nils. If it can contain nil, it _must_ consist entirely of Optionals. Your `[1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7]` is possible only if this is an `[Int?]` (an array of optionals wrapping Int) and `1` is actually `Optional(1)` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said in the comments, you want to print the array in this kind of format:

```
[1, 2, 3, nil, 5, nil, 7]
```

instead of this:

```
[Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(3), nil, Optional(5), nil, Optional(7)]
```

You can use a for loop that checks whether each element is nil. If it is nil, print "nil", else, unwrap and print the number.

But that would be too much code to write, wouldn't it? You will have to handle the placement of the commas and `[]`. So I came up with this little trick... You might not like it though:

```
final class Nil: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String = "nil"
}

let a: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, nil, 5, nil, 7] // this is your original array
let b: [AnyObject] = a.map { $0 as AnyObject? ?? Nil() }
print(b)
```

I admit that this isn't clean, but I mean, it's less code after all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question don't have sense. You storing `nil` to be able have "empty" element. So, you anyway need to check every element for `nil`.

Just follow well known optional binding pattern:

```
var array: [Int?] = [1,2,3,nil,5,nil,7]
if let element = array[3] {
    //do smtng
}
```

or drop all `nil` off

```
let nilFree = array.flatMap{$0}
//[1,2,3,5,7]
```

Custom printing of `Array<Optional<T>>` example:

```
print(array.map {nullable -> AnyObject in return nullable ?? "nil"})
//[1, 2, 3, nil, 5, nil, 7]
```

Comment: I want to store empty elements, that's the case

Comment: @DCDC use optionals. Please provide real case when you have problem with this. Also, try to think about type of array you wish to construct.

Comment: let's say I need to have exact 10 elements array, and after unwrapping I need to know where value and where nil occur

Comment: @DCDC let's say I need to have exact 10 elements array, and after unwrapping I need to know where value and where nil occur - To do this loop through each and individual element in array, use conditional unwrapping for each element of array during conditional unwrapping you will know which index of array has value and which index of array has nil.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question, but don't quite know why you're already correct.

You use an array of optionals because like you said, even you don't know if something is an Int or Optional. Loop over the array and attempt an unwrap with `let`, and then do whatever you need to do. Having [Optional(1), Optional(2)...] is correct because `[1,nil,2,nil,3]` is actually an array of optional Ints (Int?), and an array must have a certain type declaration.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this,

```
var optionalIntArray: [Int?]
optionalIntArray = [1, 2, 3, nil, 4, 5]
```

When you print the array using print() you'll see it like this,

```
[optional(1),optional(2)...]
```

That is correct output because, your array is supposed to hold optional int which will be represented as

> optional(1)

for an integer optional value 1.

If you want to iterate over the optionalIntArray and add only the unwrapped values, use flatMap() on array like,

```
let arrayContainingUnwrappedValues = optionalIntArray.flatMap{$0}
arrayContainingUnwrappedValues
```